# Nginx conf file with perl software

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, perl

I have successfully installed a Perl application on my Ubunti 20.4 LEMP stack, and I can access it on: `http://example.com:5762/login.pl` and `http://example.com:5762/setup.pl`
I want to install and access the software through a subdirectory in the `foo` folder: `example.com/foo` I have modified the configuration file but when I click there, I get page not found error like [this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrLyP.jpg) and I am unable to access the software on the subdirectory URL. My Nginx configuration file is below. What do I miss to be able to access the application through the subdirectory URL: `example.com/foo`?

```
## Nginx Configuration File
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server
{
  listen 80 ;
  listen [::]:80 ;

  # SSL configuration
  #
  # listen 443 ssl default_server;
  # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
  #
  # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
  # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
  #
  # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
  # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
  #
  # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
  # Don't use them in a production server!
  #
  # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

  root /var/www/example.com/html/root;

  # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
  index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  server_name example.com www.example.com;

  location /
  {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
  #
  location ~ \.php$
  {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  }

  # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
  # concurs with Nginx's one
  #
  location ~ /\.ht
  {
    deny all;
  }
## I added this block to access the Perl application on the /foo subdirectory 
  location /foo/
  {
    root /var/www/example.com/html/root;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @starman;
  }

  # Configuration files don't exist
  location @starman
  {
    # If you changed the port in the Starman service file, change it here too
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5762;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_cookie_path ~^/$ /foo/;
   }
 }

# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

Comment: You need to reconfigure the application. This error does not come from nginx, but from your app.

Comment: My issue is similar to: https://github.com/ledgersmb/ledgersmb-docker/issues/27